# A mySQL count query to return a numeric value?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a database set up with a few hundred customers in, all of them are unique. However, some customers are linked together, if they are part of a family. E.g.

I have a family ID that links these customers, e.g.  Mrs A. Jones is customer number 005 and Mr B.Jones is customer number 017 and as they are related, I have assigned them family ID 001.

I've searched online, but no where seems to be that useful at providing me with any assistance into how I could do some sort of mySQL count to echo the number of people WHERE familyID = 001.

Also, is there any way, I could return both seperate customer records, given the mySQL search criteria of familyID = 001.

Many thanks,

Tom.

EDIT: Realised I'd put passenger instead of customers, my bad! Also, the names are made up for obvious DPA reasons :)

Comment: Can you post sample data and desired o/p?

Comment: passenger records?? where did this passenger came from...u where talking about customers right?

Answer (score 2):

You want the `COUNT()` function

```
SELECT count(*) AS count FROM customers WHERE familyID="001"
```

You can replace the `*` with a column name, makes it a little faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the count Function in such cases .it can be used as.

```
Select count(*) form TABLE NAME where familyID = "001"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql='SELECT count(familyID) AS count FROM customers WHERE familyID="001"';
```

Here you can get number of customers of familyID= 001

But where is this passenger came from? what is the relation with customer?

If it is about customer not passenger then

```
 $sql='SELECT * FROM customers WHERE familyID="001"';
    $query=mysql_query($sql);
    $count=mysql_num_rows($query);
    while($fetch_arr=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
      $familyName=$fetch_arr['name'];
      echo  $familyName;
     }
```

You can get all records from * and from $count u can get number of customers

Answer (score 0):

If you want the unique records as well as the count use this, with the `OVER` function:

```
SELECT customers.id, 
    customers.additional_columns, 
    count(1) OVER (PARTITION BY familyID) AS count 
FROM customers
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM families where familyID='001'", $link);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

[source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)

Answer (score -1):

For your first question, this will do

```
$result = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE familyID = '001'");
echo mysql_num_rows($result); //This line should display the count
```

Comment: -1 for using the `@` operator in a totally useless and uncalled-for manner.